# Flutter: Unable to read data from firebase. The method '[]' was called on null error

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, stream-builder, flutter-widget

I am trying to read the data from firebase after scanning a barcode.

This is how it should appear, but instead of barcode, it should display name and price from the database
(https://m.imgur.com/gallery/lEFJZ0Q)

[image: I am reading from prd which has details of barcode]

Code:

```
class ListTileModel {
  String barcode;
  ListTileModel(this.barcode);
}
```

the below code is inside the stateful widget

```
List<ListTileModel> _items = [];
String barcode = "";

  void _add() {
    _items.add(ListTileModel(barcode));
      setState(() {});
  }


  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
  }
```

StreamBuiler Used:

```
new Container(

              child: ListView(
                  children: _items
                      .map((item) => StreamBuilder(
                  stream: FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('prd').child(item.barcode).onValue,
                  builder: (context, snap) {
                    print(item.barcode);
                    if(snap.hasData){
                      DataSnapshot snapshot = snap.data.snapshot;
                      Map<dynamic, dynamic> itm = snapshot.value;
                      return snap.data.snapshot.value == null
                          ? SizedBox()
                          : ListView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                        itemCount: 1,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return Row(
                            children: <Widget>[

                              ConstrainedBox(

                                child: Container(

                                  child: Text(itm[index]['name'],style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),),
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(width: 100,),
                              ConstrainedBox(

                                child: Container(

                                  child: Text(itm[index]['price'].toString(),style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          );
                        },
                      );
                    }
                    else {
                      return   Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                    }
                  }
              ),
                  ).toList()
              ),
            ),
```

The Barcode Scan code:

widget:

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: scan,
        child: Icon(Icons.add_shopping_cart),

      ),
```

scan() :

```
Future scan() async{
    try{
      String barcode = await BarcodeScanner.scan();
        setState(() {
          this.barcode = barcode;
        });
      _add();
    }on PlatformException catch(e) {
      if(e.code == BarcodeScanner.CameraAccessDenied){
        setState(() {
          this.barcode = 'Access Denied';
        });
      }
    }
```

I'm am getting following Error:

The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building:
The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling:

Comment: i think you are not getting value because their is det is also there. give try to following query.                  stream: FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('prd').child(item.barcode).child('det').onValue,

Comment: @VirenVVarasadiya I tried it but same error

Comment: The issue is resolved referring to @wcyankees424 suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this and let me know if it fixes your problem you need to change

```
Text(itm[index]['name'],style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),),

Text(itm[index]['price'].toString(),style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),),
```

To

```
Text(itm['det']['name'],style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),),

Text(itm['det']['price'].toString(),style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),),
```

Let me know if this works for you. I believe the problem is the index also.
right now your saying.

Comment: I tried it but still the same error:

The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building:
The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: []("det")

Comment: yes I tried, I don't think passing the barcode as index works. I got the same error

Comment: im sorry i didn't see its part of your stream

Comment: I got one more.

Comment: try taking the index out all together

Comment: Yes, it's working Thank you. I kept the same stream and changed  itm['det']['name']